# Existential Instantiation

Tags: logic

We know from calculus:if f is a continuous function, for any $x_0$, for any $\epsilon$, there exists a $\delta$ depending on the $\epsilon$ such that if $|x-x_0|< \delta$, then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|< \epsilon$.

Fix $f(x)= x$. We can pick $\delta= \epsilon$ as substitution. Existential instantiation from logic states that $\delta$ must not appear anywhere already in the Knowledge Base. Is there any contradiction?

Comment: ...... What are you trying to show? .....

Comment: Are you trying to show that $f$ is continuous, and you are wondering if $\delta=\epsilon$ is a good choice for $\delta$?

Comment: A clarification of the Existential Instantiation inference rule. How do we justify the epsilon-delta we learned in calculus?

Comment: I am even more confused now ... Are you trying to justify something using the epsilon delta rule, or are you trying to justify the epsilon delta rule itself?

Comment: You refer to a requirement that $\delta$ not appear in the Knowledge base. What does the term Knowledge base refer to? And what does it mean to "appear" in that base?

Comment: Knowledge base is a computer science term for the "set" of all true statements in some world. See Russell and Norvig, Aritifical Intelligence A Modern Approach.

Comment: I don't know about "knowledge bases," but in a formal proof, the only restriction on existential instantiation is that the free variable introduced not previously occur as a free variable in any statement in that proof.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you are asking whether or not you can use existential instantiation to infer from that $\forall \epsilon \exists \delta ...$ statement that $\delta $ can be assumed to be $\epsilon$ in the case $f(x)=x$

I would say no. While in that case it would indeed be *true* that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|< \epsilon$ if $|x -x_0|<\delta$ and $\delta = \epsilon$, you cannot regard that as a proper instance of existential elimination (once you fix $\epsilon$) for exactly the reason you indicate: we cannot assume that the $\delta $ is some specific object we are already referring to (in this case $\epsilon$). If it turns out that the claim is true with $\delta$ being one of those already defined objects, then you may be able to prove that later on, but you can't assume that just using existential instantiation.

Comment: So we are using Skolemization and not existential elimination?

Comment: @user352102 If you fix the $\epsilon$, than you can do existential instantiation and just fill in a constant for $\delta$, but it would have to be a new/fresh constant.  But if you leave the $\epsilon$ as a variable and Skolemize, then you need to use $f(\epsilon)$ for your $\delta$

Comment: actually, I think Skolemization and existential elimination (or existential instantiation) are the same thing. The "new" symbol is the **function** $\delta(\epsilon)$????

Comment: @user352102 Well, I can see how someone might not make a difference, but I see existential elimination as a rule in a formal proof/derivation system that applies to an existential statement (i.e. you can only eliminate the existential when the existential is the *main* connective ... an in the process you replace the quantified variables with a fresh constant), whereas skolemization is a technique mostly used in resolution, where you can eliminate existential quantifiers that are not necessarily the main operator ... but the statement has to be in Prenex Normal Form ... (continued)

Comment: @user352102 ... (continued) ... and you also need to introduce a function if the existential is preceded by any universals.   And no, the function is not $\delta(\epsilon)$, but some fresh function $f(\epsilon)$. That is, the delta that you can pick is dependent on what $\epsilon$ you pick, so we treat the delta to pick as a function of epsilon

Answer (score 0):

In existential instantiation you can instantiate the quantified variable with any available term you like including delta in your example. With universal introduction and existential elimination the situation is different. There you must choose a fresh name.

To show forall x.phi we choose a fixed but arbitrary c and prove phi[x:=c]. Often one uses x itself for the fresh name.

To use an assumption exists x.phi we  choose a fixed but arbitrary c and use phi[x:=c]. Often one uses x itself for the fresh name.

To prove exists x.phi we exhibit any witnessing expression t and prove phi[x:=t].

To use an assumption forall x.phi we exhibit any witnessing expression t and use phi[x:=t].

To prove forall x0. forall eps.exists delta.forall x.|x-x0| < delta -> |x-x0|< eps

we choose fixed but arbitrary x0 and eps which happen to be fresh at that point. Then pick the witnessing term eps for delta. But note that we could pick any other term, e.g. 1/2*eps. Let's do that for clarity. OK and then we choose y as a fresh name for x (Just for variation). So, we are left with the quantifier-free stmt

|y-x0|<1/2*eps -> |y-x0|

which is true.